# Making an entire DIV clickable while using Rails to send a POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, counter, clickable

I'm really new to web development (I started my "education" about 3 months ago) and totally new to stackoverflow... I'm having some trouble with a webapp I've been building.

**Everything about the following code works as intended.**

```
        <div class ="large-4 columns" span id="trait_list">
            <%= link_to "#{n.name} #{Trait.find(n.id).trait_user.first(:conditions => ["trait_id = #{n.id} AND user_id = #{current_user.id}"]).counter} Times" , counter_index_path(:trait_id => n), method: :POST %>
        </div>
```

Where(      @usertrait = current_user.traits.all ) in the controller.

(counter_index_path) points to a table where a specific users-traits counter is increased by 1 in the trait_user table. I understand that some of the above code should be placed in the controller... but I just haven't found a way to do it correctly yet **>^..^<**

**Problem**

A colleague recently asked that the divs that contain the links be clickable as well. I've found a few solutions.... the first of which being to add the following code to

**CSS**,

```
{ 
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;

  /* edit: added z-index */
  z-index: 1;

  /* edit: fixes overlap error in IE7/8, 
     make sure you have an empty gif */
  background-image: url('empty.gif');
}
```

Which somehow removes the text that's supposed to be displayed in the div...

**JQuery**

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location.href="http://google.com";
    return false;
});
```

This causes the links to send a GET Method when I need a POST method to be sent (to increase the counter number by 1)...

I'm not sure if there's already been an answer to this, but i've not been able to find it. Help is really welcome ^.^

*Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", your_method);
    form.setAttribute("action", your_path);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
});
```